# Mostrar fecha entre fechas, en ASP.NET Core (MVC)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc

Al buscar la fecha, omite el dia actual, por ejemplo, si hago un registro del dia de hoy y hago la busqueda no me sale este ultimo registro, para que pueda salir necesito colocar un dia mas.[image: Este es mi controlador]
[image: Esta es mi Vista/Index][image: Quiero que me mande la asistencia del 27][image: No me la da, a menos que le coloque el dia 28]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit]. Asi como esta no se entiende nada de tu problema...

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que estas usando un tipo de dato que se llama 'DateTime', que como su nombre indica es la fecha y hora, cuando comparas contra una fecha en realidad comparas con esa fecha iniciando el día a las 00:00 por lo que no te sale cualquier luego de esa hora, en tu metodo de busqueda debes sumar un día a la fecha final y comparar con un menor extricto "<" para que te incluya los eventos del día seleccionado.